# Where should I register the spark UDF for a generic function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a generic function which gets executed multiple times for different parameters. This method uses an UDF to manipulate date and year. Is it a good practice to register UDF within the method where it is called? If not, which is the best practice and what is the performance hit by registering the same UDF again and again?

```
def get_date_from_year_and_month(year_month):
    """Returns year and month in the format YYYY-MM.
    year, month = year_month

    return str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2)

def function_that_uses_udf(param):
    # Should this be done outside the function?
    get_date_from_year_and_month_udf = F.udf(get_date_from_year_and_month)

    df = df_old.withColumn(
    'date', get_date_from_year_and_month_udf(F.struct([F.col('year'), F.col('month')]))
```

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks for your answering the best practice. I am also conserned about knowing the performance effect on registering the same UDF in a loop. Spark, being lazy, how does it work in the background for this register.

Answer (score 1):

Where, as in like this, for example, and every time via the spark context:

```
def squared(s):
   return s * s

spark.udf.register("squaredWithPython", squared)
```

Not like Hive where this can be stored in a database.